# ReactDOM.createPortal() is creating extra blank divs in next.js-typescript

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-portal

this is backdrop.tsx:

```
interface BacdropProps {
  open?: string;
  onClick: () => void;
}

const Backdrop: React.FC<BacdropProps> = (props) => {
  let container: HTMLDivElement | null = null;
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const rootContainer = document.createElement("div");
    const parentElem = document.querySelector("#__next");
    parentElem?.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", rootContainer);
    // parentElem?.after(rootContainer) this gives me same issue
    container = rootContainer;
  }

  return container
    ? ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <div
          className={["backdrop", props.open ? "open" : ""].join(" ")}
          onClick={props.onClick}
        />,
        container
      )
    : null;
};

export default Backdrop;
```

this is css for Backdoor.tsx

```
.backdrop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

this is how it looks:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will create `div.backdrop` every time when `Backdrop` re-render. The correct way should be create it once. The correct way is using `useEffect` to promise `ReactDOM.createPortal` just be executed once. And also apply the `useRef` to make sure `container` to keep the same instance in every render.

```
const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

useEffect({
  // Will be execute once in client-side
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const rootContainer = document.createElement("div");
    const parentElem = document.querySelector("#__next");
    parentElem?.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", rootContainer);
    // parentElem?.after(rootContainer) this gives me same issue
    containerRef.current = rootContainer;
  }
}, [window])

useEffect({
  // Will be execute once when containerRef is bind to <HTMLDivElement>
  if(containerRef.current) {
    ReactDOM.createPortal(
      <div
        className={["backdrop", props.open ? "open" : ""].join(" ")}
        onClick={props.onClick}
      />,
      containerRef.current
    )
  }
}, [containerRef])
```

**Edit**

1. I removed the detection of existence in `window`, since `useEffect` would be executed only in client-side.
2. Since `ReactDOM.createPortal` will create the `div.backdrop` outside of the root `HTMLElement` (`div#next`), i think just return `null` in `Backdrop` component is fine.

```js
const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

useEffect({
  // useEffect would run just in client-side
  const rootContainer = document.createElement("div");
  const parentElem = document.querySelector("#__next");
  parentElem?.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", rootContainer);
  // parentElem?.after(rootContainer) this gives me same issue
  containerRef.current = rootContainer;
}, [])

useEffect({
  // Will be execute once when containerRef is bind to <HTMLDivElement>
  if(containerRef.current) {
    ReactDOM.createPortal(
      <div
        className={["backdrop", props.open ? "open" : ""].join(" ")}
        onClick={props.onClick}
      />,
      containerRef.current
    )
  }
}, [containerRef])

return null;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. i have 2 issues. why are we using [window]. currently it says "window" is not defined. Looks like it was rendered on the server. 2nd issue, what am I gonna return in the component?

Comment: since my question asks how to solve the issue of extra divs, and you handled the question. I accepted your answer and liked the answer. but i have another component modal and it is mounted on the dom but it does not show on the screen. Can you please chech this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65914360/reactdom-createportal-modal-is-mounted-on-dom-but-nothing-is-displayed-on-the-sc